# How to chain map and filter functions with good readability?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to use the code below.
But I'm not sure it's readable.
I wonder if there is a code style commonly used in method chaining that improves the readability of this code. (like indentation, line breaks, etc.)

#### Question

How to increase this code's readability? Any recommendation?

```
const words = Object.entries(data).map((item) => item[1].words.filter((v) => v.wordId)));
```

**Input data**

```
//data looks like this
[
  {
    id: '...',
    words: { id:1, wordId: '0nN1R9AlPGrH67', word: {text:'aa', originalText:'aa'} },
  },
]
```

**Expected output**

I want to extract only the value where `wordId` exists.

#### Try

```
const words = Object.entries(data)
        .map((item) => item[1].words
            .filter((v) => v.wordId)),
        );
```

Comment: Are you asking about the usage of the functions, the way their callbacks are formatted, or are you asking about the formatting (the indentation, line breaks, etc.)?

Comment: 1) One-liners are always a poor choice for readability. 2) What does your input data/expected output look like?

Comment: This question might be better for codereview stackexchange

Comment: @cSharp I'm asking about formatting like indentation, line breaks etc! Sorry for confusion

Comment: @qwr oh I didn't know about codereview stackexchange. thanks for recommend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, instead of writing a one line chain, you could break it down into multiple variables and combine them. This should increase code modularity and make it more readable. See an example below:

```
const objData = Object.entries(data);
const callbackFilter = (item) => item[1].words.filter((v) => v.wordId);
const dataArray = objData.map(callbackFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
let data = [
  {
    id: '...',
    words: { id:1, wordId: '0nN1R9AlPGrH67', word: {text:'aa', originalText:'aa'} },
  },
  {
    id: '...',
    words: { id:2, wordId:"", word: {text:'aa', originalText:'aa'} },
  },
];

const words = data.filter(item => item.words?.wordId !== undefined);

console.log(words)
```